# Looping for dynamic pictures

Tags: excel, vba

So I have created a dynamic selection list for excel using vba. see below

[image: excel workbook]

[image: dynamic image]

Below is the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
    Call PanggilPhoto
End If
End Sub


Sub PanggilPhoto()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim myObj
Dim Foto
Set myObj = ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects
For Each Foto In myObj
If Left(Foto.Name, 7) = "Picture" Then
Foto.Select
Foto.Delete
End If
Next
Dim CommodityName1 As String, CommodityName2 As String, T As String


myDir = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
CommodityName1 = Range("A2")
T = ".png"

Range("C15").Value = CommodityName
On Error GoTo errormessage:
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=myDir & CommodityName1 & T, _
linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoTrue, Left:=190, Top:=10, Width:=140, 
Height:=90

errormessage:If Err.Number = 1004 Then
Exit Sub
MsgBox "File does not exist." & vbCrLf & "Check the name of the Commodity!"
Range("A2").Value = ""
Range("C10").Value = ""

End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

foto is a predefined data list in the sheet.

So the question is instead of doing it for one cell how can I create a loop of some sort to do it for multiple cells? I need it to import mulitple images on one macro run

[image: multicells]

Comment: Welcome to SO. *how can I create a loop* You can create a loop with `For...Loop`. Google for it. Also, consider adding arguments yo your sub to draw a different figure each time is called. [PAssing Values to a Sub](http://www.homeandlearn.org/passing_values_to_a_sub.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        Call schedules
    End If
End Sub

Sub schedules()

Worksheets("Picture").Activate





Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim myObj
Dim Foto
Set myObj = ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects
For Each Foto In myObj
If Left(Foto.Name, 7) = "Picture" Then
Foto.Select
Foto.Delete
End If
Next

Dim CommodityName1 As String, CommodityName2 As String, T1 As String, T2 As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

j = 0



For i = 2 To 100




myDir = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ESTIMATING SHEETS\test\rebar shapes" & "\"
CommodityName1 = Range("A" & i)
T1 = ".png"




On Error GoTo errormessage:
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=myDir & CommodityName1 & T1, _
linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoTrue, Left:=230, Top:=j, Width:=140, Height:=80



errormessage:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
Exit Sub
MsgBox "File does not exist." & vbCrLf & "Check the name of the rebar!"
Range("A" & i).Value = ""
Range("C10").Value = ""

End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
i = i + 11
j = j + 190
Next i


End Sub
```